# Mysql Invalid character error bypassing

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8

Got the error while updating the table:

`SQL Error (1300): Invalid utf8 character string: 'C9'`

- How to find, which row causes error?

  `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ROW LIKE CONCAT('%',0xC9,'%')` didn't help
- How to bypass the problematic row and update others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a copy of the table, remove encoding, set string to binary, and then search for that string. When you're also into scripting, you could test each row independently.